# What do "JAMZ", "JAMN", and "JMPC" stand for in Mic-1?

Tags: computer-architecture

I am wondering what do `JAMZ`, `JAMN`, and `JMPC` stand for in Tanenbaum's Mic-1 architecture. I know that `MPC`, the control store’s memory address register, stands for "MicroProgram Counter", but what does `J` mean? Likewise, there are 1-bit flip-flops where the values of `N` and `Z` are latched. The book says that if `JAMN` is set, the 1-bit `N` flip-flop is ORed into the high-order bit of `MPC`. Similarly, if `JAMZ` is set, the 1-bit `Z` flip-flop is ORed there. If both are set, both are ORed there. Effectively, this changes the address of the next instruction to be executed. So, it looks like `J` has something to do with "jump", but I'm not quite sure that's the case. The book does not spell out the names anywhere, just abbreviations. I also assume that `N` has to do with "negative", and `Z` with "zero", but those are just wild guesses.

Here is the Mic-1 microinstruction format:

[image: Mic-1 microinstruction format:]

Here is the Mic-1 block diagram:

[image: Mic-1 block diagram]

Comment: I don't know, hence a comment instead of an answer, but I think actually that it is the word _jam_, (packing things tightly together). And JAM is signalled by the ALU that too many bits are set or something ... But I'm on really thin ice here.

Comment: @PålGD, that is actually a reasonable interpretation.

Comment: Well, I don't have any references, so I hesitate to turn it into an answer ... you could consider whether it would have better luck at [eletronics.stackexchange:microcontroller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microcontroller).

Comment: The Mic-1 is described in *Structured computer organization*, 6th ed., by Andrew Tanenbaum and Todd Austin, 2012, Pearson.

Comment: It was just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

From this reference: http://wtkrieger.faculty.noctrl.edu/csc220_winter2014/lecture/note22.pdf,

12 bits control the selection of the next microinstruction:

- Addr (9 bits) - the address of the next micro-instruction
- JAM (3 bits) - these bits determine how the next micro-instruction is chosen

JAM bits are complicated.

- JMPC = use the PC address
- JAMN = if N is true (negative result in ALU), then add 1 to high-order bit of Addr
- JAMZ = if Z is true (zero result in ALU), then add 1 to high-order bit of Add

Answer (score 0):

Dont know the meaning of JMPC but I do know that both, JAMN and JAMZ are just Flags, which show that the result of the ALU is negativ or zero.

Edit: I think they use the flags and are relevant for using if in MAL. (Correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: (Can you provide a [reference](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) for *Mic-1 JAMN* and *JAMZ* being *Flags*?)

Comment: Okay I correct myself. They USE the flags. In my documents (also Tannenbaum) it says: "The syntax for telling the microassembler to set the JAMZ bit is   if(Z) goto L1; else goto L2"

Comment: (In my book, not every *bit field* is a *flag*. Flags indicate something, bit fields in *microinstructions* control something with little decoding or none at all.)